# Why same code builded with javac and gradle behave different?

Tags: java, gradle

```
switch (readChoice()) {
  //options
}

private static int readChoice() {
    String input;
    int choice = -1;
    try {
        input = scanner.next();
        choice = Integer.parseInt(input);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        logger.error("Error while trying to read choice from the console", e);
        }
    }
    return choice;

}
```

When i build this code with javac, everything works fine. But when i try to run code builded with gradle, i get this

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1371)
    at edu.java.core.cinema.Main.readChoice(Main.java:207)
    at edu.java.core.cinema.Main.main(Main.java:42)
```

42 - there is switch, 207 - there is scanner.next().
Scanner tries to read choice, when there is nothing to read.
I just started to learn gradle, so maybe i did mistake with building.
I build and run project with gradle wrapper

```
$ gradle wrapper --gradle-version 3.4
$ ./gradlew build
$ ./gradlew run
```

UPDATE:
There is build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'edu.java.core.cinema.Main'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

jar {
    baseName = 'lab2'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ["src"]

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
   compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.0'

   compile group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: '1.2.2'

   compile group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-core', version: '1.2.2'

   compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.25'

}
```

Comment: When Gradle runs this, it doesn't prompt for input?

Comment: @cricket_007 what do you mean?

Comment: `scanner.next()` should pause and wait for input on your terminal

Comment: @cricket_007 yes, but for some reason with Gradle it doesn't wait

Comment: Which are the lines in the code that throw the exception?

Comment: What is your gradle build file?

Comment: OK, best thing to do now is create a small simple single class that in its main method creates a scanner and tries to do scanner.next. Use the most basic gradle build file and if the error still happens post that. This will eliminate all other suspicions.

Comment: @Mark same error

Comment: Post those files so we can run it.

Comment: @Mark https://github.com/Pechorka/gradle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your gradle build file add

```
run {
    standardInput = System.in
}
```

to redirect the "gradle input" to `system.in`. If you don't it's empty and will fail when trying to read input.